# Adobe Analytics API JSON query

Tags: json, adobe-analytics

I'm looking into how to report multiple breakdowns using the reporting API. Ultimately I would like to make a JSON request that returns top level data, and and second level breakdown data, for all rows of top level data (not just specific rows).

A useful guide is https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/blob/master/reporting-multiple-breakdowns.md

This is clearly designed for someone who wishes to write code which, for instance, takes the itemID from the top level response and uses this to retrieve second level breakdown data. Unfortunately I currently just have access to the Swagger UI.

Is there one piece of JSON code I can run (in the UI) that would return both top level data, and the associated second level breakdown data for all top level rows? Or is this only possible if I write some code?

Answer (score 1):

Hate to break it to you but multiple requests and doing some nested iterations through a few JSON objects isn't even the hardest part about all this. Making use of the API means coding. Why are you using Swagger UI for this vs. just logging into the Adobe Analytics web interface? On that note..

If you want to keep it as simple as possible, I would suggest you login to the Adobe Analytics web interface and create your desired report in the Analysis Workspace. Because Analysis Workspace uses the same API 2.0 interface to pull the data, you can follow the guide from the Adobe API 2.0 docs to [get the JSON used to build the reports](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/blob/master/reporting-tricks.md), which you can then use in Swagger UI.

But I am legit curious about why you are trying to pull data using Swagger UI if you aren't looking to code anything, vs. logging into AA web interface for reports.

Comment: Swagger as I don't currently have developer access so I can't get hold of an OAuth token via the Adobe IO console, and get coding. JSON because Workspace freeform tables are limited to 400 rows. Adobe Analytics Reports don't appear to have this limit, but I can't add time as a second dimension to a ranked report, and 'trended' reports end up looking rather odd and unusable....